# Issue for deploying NodeJS on a virtual server machine

Tags: node.js, ssh, deployment, server

I have a NodeJs app which works well on my local machine.

Now, I would like to deploy it on a virtual machine with a given IP and a given http address.

Assume for my case that the ip and the http address of the server are respectively **134.00.00.00** and **http://server-virtualmachine.is.fr**

I was able to connect via ssh to this server and send my Node JS app to **/var/www/**

The main file of the server is **app.js** so I have executed this following command line to run the server.

```
node app.js
```

The output is :

```
App listening on port 3030 with adress 134.00.00.00
```

I have no error. However, by checking directly on my browser at http://134.00.00.00:3030 or http://server-virtualmachine.is.fr:3030, the connexion is not established and my browser finally end up by showing this message :

```
134.00.00.00 took too many times to answer
```

If I'm going to the address without writing the port (http://134.00.00.00), I have the following message :

```
Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

Then, in order to see where the problem is, I tried just to set up a hello world example file.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(3030, '134.00.00.00');
console.log('Server running at 134.00.00.00:3030');
```

Same problem appears. However, I opened a new tab and open a new SSH connection and executed the following command line :

```
curl http://134.00.00.00:3030
```

By surprise, I have on my terminal `"Hello world"`

I'm not really into server and I tried to understand by myself but now I does not understand this issue and how to solve it.

I would like to have my NodeJs app working on a virtual machine and not on my local machine.

Any insights ?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Is port 3030 open?

Comment: It should be because an old Node Js - Angular JS project was working before on this virtual machine with this port. How can I check if It's open ? Otherwise is there a way to see which port is open ? Thank

Comment: You can check it in firewall settings. Or use `nmap` command

Comment: Thank you ! I could check and It was close. I have opened it and now everything works ! Thank !

Answer (score 0):

Thank to Ebrahim Pasbani, I could see that my port 3030 was not open. In order to check that, I used the following command line :

```
nmap ip
```

and more specifically `nmap -p3030 ip`

I opened it and now it works.